# Rails server ( Spreecommerce - Thin ) does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, server, spree, cloud9-ide

I have troubles starting my rails app within cloud 9 IDE. I know I have to declare the port and Ip as such when starting the server( rails server -b $IP -p $PORT ), also tried declaring a specific port number. thent I ended some processes with kill -9 XXXX. After this I deleted server.pid as suggested on this forum.  No results.
This is the error I keep receiving. Can anyone help me read the error message. I think the error is somewhere generated due to a incomplete gemfile. Thanks in advance

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelisted_ransackable_associations' for # (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree_i18n/translatable.rb:9:in `block in '
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree/property_decorator.rb:4:in `include'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree/property_decorator.rb:4:in `block in '
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree/property_decorator.rb:2:in `class_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree/property_decorator.rb:2:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/app/models/spree/property_decorator.rb:1:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/lib/spree_i18n/engine.rb:36:in `block in activate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/lib/spree_i18n/engine.rb:35:in `glob'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-6c9ea5adb298/lib/spree_i18n/engine.rb:35:in `activate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in '
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/config.ru:3:in `block in '
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/config.ru:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/bin/rails:8:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/bin/spring:13:in `'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `'
```

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
#Ruby toevoegen om spree op Heroku te kunnen laden"
#gem 'ruby', '2.2.2'

group :production do
  gem 'shelly-dependencies'
end
# Thin toevoegen omdat Shellycloud het vraagt
gem 'thin', '1.6.3'

#internationalisatie 
gem 'spree_i18n', :github => 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n' ,branch:'3-0-stable'
```

Comment: looks almost like missing gem dependencies, or a version mismatch somewhere.   have you tried refreshing your bundle?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the server issue. Please check your file dynamic_matchers.rb line number 26, where you have defined the method, whitelisted_ransackable_associations. This is wrongly typed. Change the name of this method to correct one.

Comment: thank you for the advice. There was no such method in dynamic_matchers.rb ( neither on another line in this file). I went a few commits back. My server works when i install the spree commerce gem . But when I try to install the spree_i18n. He gives me the same kind of error. It is when I try to run this command: bundle exec rails g spree_i18n:install